# ムダ足だった == useless leg?

Tags: kanji, set-phrases, idioms, past

When I look up the phrase 無駄足だった, I see it translated as "It was a Wild goose chase." I found this bizarre, since it seems like it would mean "It was a useless foot/leg." is this some sort of figure of speech that means the same or something similar to "wild goose chase" or am I missing something? Thanks for any help.

Comment: 「せっかくそこまで足を運んだのに、そのかいがないこと。〈=無駄だった〉」

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe [無駄足]{むだあし} is derived from [無駄足]{むだあし}を[運]{はこ}ぶ ("move one's feet in vain"), which is one of a series of counterintuitive idioms Japanese vocabulary has.

- **[小腹]{こばら}が[減]{へ}る** "little stomach get empty"
  actually describing "be a little hungry" (cf. [腹]{はら}が[減]{へ}る "be hungry")
- **[大]{おお}ぼらを[吹]{ふ}く** "blow on a big conch"
  actually, "blow on a conch loudly" or "tell a tall story" (cf. ほらを[吹]{ふ}く "talk big")
  eventually [大]{おお}ぼら itself stands for "tall story".
- **[横車]{よこぐるま}を[押]{お}す** "push a side cart"
  actually, "push cart from the side" or "ram through"
  eventually [横車]{よこぐるま}, "unreasonable demand".
- **[後ろ]{うしろ}[髪]{がみ}を[引]{ひ}かれる** "be pulled by the rear hair"
  actually, "be pulled by the hair from behind" or "too sorry to leave"
- **[無駄骨]{むだぼね}を[折]{お}る** "break a useless bone"
  actually, "break a bone in vain" or "make vain efforts" (cf. [骨]{ほね}を[折]{お}る "make efforts")
  eventually [無駄骨]{むだぼね}, "vain efforts".

Comment: Or 無駄**に**足を運ぶ, to make every word's meaning traceable. "2 moras + 2 moras" way of contraction is very common in Japanese, as you know, and some of them date back to pre-modern era Japanese. e.g. 藪蛇 from 藪をつついて蛇を出す, 泥縄 from 泥棒に入られて縄をなう, 眉唾 from 眉に唾をつけたくなる, etc. I think 無駄足 exactly is on of these words.